# Does a Level Sequence replicate over network?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint, unreal-engine5

I have created two level sequences, simple roll of an actor object. My goal is to be able to see those objects roll in all clients.

I do replicate the event on server and with multicast. I see that the blueprint goes up to the point to play the sequence but it is only triggered for the server.

Is it possible to trigger a sequence over network or I should use a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, if anyone stumbles upon the same issue. I triggered the sequence through the player character and it worked just fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).